# Обнулить поля если ключи строки и коллекции совпали

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть PL/SQL код:

```
for elem in 1 .. some_array.count loop
    UPDATE my_table
    SET name = null
    WHERE id = some_array(elem).id;
end loop;
```

Здесь в цикле обнуляются поля `name`, если в `some_array` присутструет `id` этой строки.

Как это сделать более элегантно, в одну-две строки?

При этом откатить (`rollback`), если что-то пойдет не так (при любой ошибке)?

Comment: цель избавиться от цикла? rollback же и в примере работает...

Comment: @4per как работает? Например на 10м элементе что-то сломалось, все данные вернутся к первоначальному состоянию?

Comment: ну вызвать rollback или commit решите вы или ваша программа, а откатить можно к началу транзакции.

Comment: @4per вы сказали, что "rollback же и в примере работает". Что это значит? Можно не писать всяких savepoint a; rollback to a; оно само вернется к изначальному состоянию?

Comment: `savepoint a; rollback to a;` это работа с вложенными транзакциями, а с обычными, достаточно выполнить DML-запрос, чтобы она началась, и вызвать commit или rollback, чтобы закончилась. Советую лучше разобраться с транзакциями, прежде чем работать с данными в производстве - ошибки с транзакциями бывают очень не приятные.

Comment: @4per на мой вопрос не ответили

Comment: А я не отвечаю, я использую комментарии для запроса дополнительной информации. Ваша цель избавиться от цикла?

Comment: @4per избавиться от цикла и откатить назад, если что-то пойдет не так при апдейте.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Где то так, 2-е строчки на update, если в одну строчку, то скролить прийдётся:

```
create type item as object (id number);
/
create or replace type itemsType as table of item;
/
create table items (id number, name varchar2(32));
/
insert into items select level, 'item '||level from dual
connect by level <= 10
;

declare
    items itemsType := itemsType (item (2), item (6), item (10));
    countNulls integer;
    countRows integer;
begin 
    update items i set name = null where exists (
        select 1 from table (items) t where t.id = i.id);
    countRows := sql%rowcount;
    select count (1) into countNulls 
    from items 
    where name is null
    ;
    dbms_output.put_line ('updated rows '||countRows||' nulls '||countNulls);
exception when others then 
    dbms_output.put_line ('error:'||sqlerrm||chr(10)||dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace());
    raise;
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

updated rows 3 nulls 3
```

В данном случае `rollback` не нужен, т.к при любом исключении в одиночном `update` ни одна из строк не будет изменена, т.е. если 999 строчек были изменены, а на 1000-й произойдёт исключение, то для всех изменений, которые произвёл текуший `update`, будет произведён неявный откат.

Обычно, в подобных случаях, запись в лог и `raise` достаточно, а вызывающая программа решает, стоит ли откатывать всю трансакцию, повторить eё, или в редких случаях, завершить с `commit`.

Если всё таки нужно игноририровать отдельные исключения, как это возможно в цикле, то надо дополнить `update` конструктом `log errors`. Например:

```
exec dbms_errlog.create_error_log (dml_table_name => 'items');

alter table items add constraint checkId check (not (id=10 and name is null));

   -- добавить последней строкой в update, остальное в блоке без изменений  
   log errors ('update') reject limit unlimited; 

--Вывод
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

updated rows 2 nulls 2

select ora_err_mesg$, ora_err_tag$, id, name from err$_items;

ОRA_ERR_MESG$                                       ORA_ERR_TAG$ ID NAME     
--------------------------------------------------- ------------ -- ------ 
ORA-02290: check constraint (DB.CHECKID) violated   update       10 (null)
```

В этом случае, данная процедура должна програмным путём на основании бизнес логики решить, прозводить ли откат или нет. Если да, то либо `savepoint updItems; <логика ...> rollback to updItems;`, либо передать исключение в вызывающую программу:

```
if items.count != countRows then raise exceptUpdItemsFailed; end if;
```